# integrate Liferay6 and Struts 2 for developing a Portlet

Tags: liferay

I am using Liferay 6. I want to integrate Liferay-6 and Struts-2 for developing a Portlet.

I have seen a example in [this Blog](http://pragmatastic.blogspot.com/2010/04/strutsfreemarker-sample-portlet-for.html).

Here the author uses Portlet class as:

```
<portlet-class>org.apache.struts2.portlet.dispatcher.Jsr168Dispatcher</portlet-class>
```

How can I get this class?

Because I see only these classes avialable

1. `com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet`
2. `com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet`
3. `javax.portlet.GenericPortlet`

Please see the screen shot here

[image: Liferay IDE: Create new project Screen]

Comment: What is your reason for wanting to use Struts? Just curious as to why you're using that over Liferay MVCPortlet or GenericPorlet? Just to be clear, I'm not saying that you're wrong, but you might be over complicating it for yourself.

Comment: Also that example you linked to is using Liferay 5.2.3, and you're using Liferay 6.1 (which is currently in Beta testing). So you may notice some inconsistencies between the two.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply type `org.apache.struts2.portlet.dispatcher.Jsr168Dispatcher` in the combo box then you would be able to use Struts 2.

Comment: Am I right in thinking you'd need to appropriate JAR file on your class path for this to compile? Or is included by default on the Liferay classpath?

Comment: Your assumption is correct: the referenced class is not provided by Liferay and should be found in a JAR from the Apache project. More information [here](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/portlet-plugin.html). Liferay has some Struts bridges itself but I believe they are quit outdated.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that brandizzi! I do tend to try and check the versions included in Liferay before using them for that reason. Especially when it come to jQuery!

Comment: I suggest using org.apache.struts2.portlet.dispatcher.Jsr286Dispatcher instead of Jsr168Dispatcher.